# Unhandled Exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am new to programming and I am working on a project using SQL and VB in Visual Studio 2013. One of the errors that has me stumped is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

This error occurs at the following line:

```
da.Fill(ds)
```

Under additional information the following message is included:

> Additional information: Invalid object name 'Complaints'.

I do have a `Form` named "Complaints" What am I missing? Thanks for any help you can provide! Please find the code below:

```
Public Class DButil
    Public cs As String

    Public Function GetDataView(ByVal sql As String) As DataView
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cs)

        da.Fill(ds)

        Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
        Return dv
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Dim strPath As String = Replace(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin\debug", "cms.mdf")
        cs = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;"
        cs += "AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\349591\349591\cms.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
        cs += "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: "I do have a form named "Complaints"" - ? It is referring to a Table called Complaints...

Comment: What's in the variable 'sql' ?

Comment: The problem is in the string passed as sql command for the DataAdapter. Show that string (sql)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys. Here is the code for the sql variable:

Comment: Private Sub LoadGrid()
        Dim sql As String

        sql = " SELECT Table.ComplaintID, Complaint.OpenDate, Status.StatusTitle, "
        sql += "Table.Location, Table.Description FROM Table "
        sql += " INNER JOIN Status ON Table.StatusID = Status.StatusID ORDER BY Table.OpenDate DESC"

        grdComplaints.DataSource = DB.GetDataView(sql)
    End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment

```
Private Sub LoadGrid() 
    Dim sql As String sql = "SELECT Table.ComplaintID, Complaint.OpenDate, Status.StatusTitle, " 
    sql += "Table.Location, Table.Description FROM Table " 
    sql += " INNER JOIN Status ON Table.StatusID = Status.StatusID ORDER BY Table.OpenDate DESC"
    grdComplaints.DataSource = DB.GetDataView(sql) 
End Sub
```

You use a field named `OpenDate` from a table named `Complaint`, but this table is not listed in the `JOIN` clause of the sql statement. You need to specify this table in the `JOIN` clause (or remove the column from the `SELECT` columns list )

Given the actual field names probably you need to set the relationship between `Table.OpenDate` and `Complaint.OpenDate`

```
Dim sql As String sql = "SELECT Table.ComplaintID, Complaint.OpenDate, Status.StatusTitle, " 
sql += "Table.Location, Table.Description FROM Table " 
sql += "INNER JOIN Status ON Table.StatusID = Status.StatusID "
sql += "INNER JOIN Complaint ON Table.OpenDate = Complaint.OpenDate " 
sql += "ORDER BY Table.OpenDate DESC"
```